# Change src path of relative paths of HTML source files

Tags: php, html

I am trying to configure an index file in that all the content gets generated under an different URL and then given back.

Because my HTML src tags all have relative paths, naturally the content gets a 404.

I request the URL: "ext.abayo.dev", the index.php of the URL requested looks like this:

```
$url = 'http://int.abayo.dev';

$data = array(
'customer' => 'customer_1',
'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
'license' => '1234656',
'uri' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
'post_vars' => ''
);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
print($result);
```

The result contains a template with content and of course CSS and JavaScript files such as:

```
<script src="/dist/jquery-ui-1.11.4/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

The absolute path SHOULD be :

```
http://int.abayo.dev/dist/jquery-ui-1.11.4/external/jquery/jquery.js
```

But becomes:

```
http://ext.abayo.dev/dist/jquery-ui-1.11.4/external/jquery/jquery.js
```

Because all my content is on my int.abayo.dev, the content cannot be found.

### -

I've tried the following in the 'ext.abayo.nl' index.php:

1. set_include_path('http://int.abayo.nl');
2. change $_SERVER variables (HTTP_HOST, DOCUMENT_ROOT, SERVER_NAME, etc)

But none seem to do what I want...

Is there any way to change the path without having to define absolute paths for every file I call?

---

**EDIT**

If I lack knowledge, please tell me, I am eager to understand how this process works.

Comment: `set_include_path` is for PHP (runs on the server) and doesn't have anything to do with the HTML (that runs in the client).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out HTML's `<base>`-tag. It sets the base URL for all the relative paths in your document.

```
<head>
    <base href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/" target="_blank">
</head>
```

Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

**Note:**
This will set ALL relative paths to use that base URL (links and everything).

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I was indeed thinking wrong. I had to search for a solution in the HTML paths. Thank you very much :)