# Is it possible to essentially view a webpage with puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I set up a very basic headless browser implementation with Puppeteer on a server, and the way I have it configured currently, I have the system scrape arbitrary websites based on user input. I then have the server send the html code of the page to a client using response.write. (I'm not actually deploying this as a solution to anything - it's really just a proof of concept.)

The results are mixed based on what website the system attempts to scrape from - but one thing they all have in common is that things like links and external stylesheets either work sporadically or not at all. My question is, is there a way to view the entire website, with clickable links and all, using Puppeteer? Or is this ridiculously impractical and totally hopeless?

If there is a way to approach this, some example code would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Links, scripts, images, CSS resources, etc... often use "relative" links.  That means the browser will combine the page domain or sometimes page domain and path with the relative link to form a full link that the browser can then request from.  When you borrow the HTML and host it on a different domain/path, these relative links are likely completely broken because the server you are hosting them on doesn't respond to them like the original host does.

Comment: You have to deal with relative paths so resources work correctly. maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674010/change-src-path-of-relative-paths-of-html-source-files

Comment: I can't tell what problem you're really trying to solve, but serving one site from another server is more about proxying the site than it is about puppeteer where you have to proxy all resources that the web page needs to work properly.  There are dozens of packages for node.js that help with proxying - that's not what puppeteer is.

Comment: @mbit I appreciate the example, but it's in PHP. Do you know of a way to do the same in JS?

Comment: can't you add it to the html before you serve it or send it to the client?

Comment: @mbit, you're right, the answer was plain html. Didn't solve all the problems I was having, but it's a good start.